# Unable to connect to Apex admin page: http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I recently installed Oracle 12c running on wondow10. I have configured Apex with embedded PL/SQL gateway using:https://o7planning.org/en/10341/installing-and-configuring-oracle-apex as per this document.

Apex configures without issue, however, my browser is not finding the admin page (Firefox/IE locally or chrome).

> I am getting "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error.

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- run command prompt (CMD) as an administrator
- type `ipconfig/release`
- type `ipconfig/renew`
- reset your browser settings to *default* values

  - how to do that? You use 3 different browsers, each of them does it differently - Google for it if you're unsure of how to to do it
- try again